# ng command is not working in visual studio

Tags: .net-core, angular-cli

Even tough google and stackexchange is full of these question, I can't seem to find the answer.

I have setup web application template with angular as frontend (.net 5.0)
i tried to add an angular component using 'ng g c component' but i'm getting an error ng is not recognized as a command.

when I try npm run ng g c component i got ng is not recognized as a script.

i have checked npm version which is 7.20.3 using visual studio 2019 latest version
ng is included in my packages.json file.

Any idea why I can't use the ng command in the package manager console?

Comment: The Package Manager Console is for NuGet, not for npm. You need a standard CMD window

Comment: well thanks for that one rather stupid, however now I am getting an error that it cannot find ng here: appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng but I see a ng.ps file in appdata\roaming\npm

Comment: Did you run `npm i -g @angular/core` at some point? That's what installs ng globally (in the path)

Comment: Not that I know of I just started a project web application with angular in visual studio so

Comment: So... do it :) it will fix the issue. You may want to read the angular getting started docs

Comment: Yes that what i'm doing know i'm following an udemy course xd, same error tough, i do have to say i don't see an angular-cli folder in my node_modules folder in my project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235626/discussion-between-technology-researcher-and-camilo-terevinto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha it does work.

I have uninstalled node.js since i had a none lts version, reinstalled the lts version
uninstalled angular/cli locally and globally and did npm cache clean

After that reinstalled angular/cli.
And that fixed the issue.